# Angular 14: Nested FormGroup not resetting validators

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I am trying to implement a nested `FormGroup`. So far, I am getting error while trying to reset the form. The form structure looks like this:

```js
form: UntypedFormGroup;

this.form = this.fb.nonNullable.group({
  f1: [''], f2: this.fb.nonNullable.array([], Validators.required),
  f3: this.fb.nonNullable.array([]), f4: this.fb.nonNullable.array([]),
  f5: this.fb.nonNullable.group({ id: ['', Validators.required] })
});
```

I noticed that required validator for the `id` field is not getting reset while resetting the overall form.

I have a similar project built on Angular 14 but there isn't any nested formgroup. But from my experience and research, I wrote `this.form.reset()` which is resetting the form with initial value but keeping the valid state of `id` field as `false`.

How this can be solved? Also the array fields are getting initialized with NULL even though I have set the formgroup & formarray to not allow NULL.

Current Logic:

```js
this.form.reset();
console.log("Form after reset:", this.form.value);
console.log("Id field valid? ", this.form.get('f5').valid);
```

Current Output:

```js
Output 1: Form after reset: {"f1":"","f2":[null],"f3":[],"f4":[],"f5":{"id":""}}
Output 2: Id field valid?  false
```

NOTE: Here I only set value of f2 field so it is only having NULL now.

Expected Output:

```js
Output 1: Form after reset: {"f1":"","f2":[],"f3":[],"f4":[],"f5":{"id":""}}
```

For the second output, the form should just reset to it's initial state as it is marking the `mat-form-field` associated with the `id` field as red.

Comment: I can't reproduce your case in v15: `Form after reset: {f1: "", f2: Array[0], f3: Array[0], f4: Array[0], …}` - property f2 is correctly reset to empty array. Regarding f5, it is invalid because `id` property is "" and it's falsy in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Per [documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#reset), control's value will be reset to initial value, if there is any, and if `nonNullable` is set to true. nonNullable does not mean that value will never be null, falsy or invalid after reset() call.

In [Validator.required() documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#required) you read that empty field value will trigger `invalid` state. There is example for zero length string:

```
const control = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
console.log(control.errors); // {required: true}
```